# ARM Assembler: Odd or Even

Tags: assembly, arm

I've been searching a while but I didn't see anything similar. I know if you have a number (i.e it will be in R1), the way you realise if the number is odd or even is checking the last byte looking for 0 or 1. How can I write this in ARM code? I think you have to compare the number with a '1' or something like that, but I don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `TST` instruction.  Try something like the following:

```
TST R1, #1
; at this point the Z flag will be set if R1 AND 1 is zero, i.e. if R1 is even,
; so you could do something like the following:
BEQ number_is_even
BNE number_is_odd
```